# How do I best return a value from an anonymous class in a method?

Tags: java, user-interface, anonymous-class

If I have a method that needs to return something, and it needs to display something on the UI to do that (for example to ask the user a question), I use `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {...});` to run it on the UI thread (Android does something similar using `runOnUiThread()`). How do I return something from that `Runnable`? For example:

```
public String askQuestion()
{
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is 2+2?");
            //how do I return this response object to the method?
        }
    });
}
```

I can't use a final local variable because the compile won't allow me to assign to it. I can use a class variable and access it using `Class.this.<variable>` but is that the best/only way to accomplish this?

Edit: I need to return things other than `String` too, this was just an example.

Comment: Can you use `java.util.concurrent.Future`? Those are typically used to return something to the main thread.

Comment: You mean `FutureTask`? Never used one before, reading up on it now.

Comment: @Heuster Actually that looks very useful indeed. I hope it works on Android too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can proceed as follows:

```
public String askQuestion()throws Exception
   {
    final StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is 2+2?");
            sBuilder.append(response);
        }
    });
   return sBuilder.toString();
}
```

This could also be solved in following way:

```
String sResponse;//make sResponse a field of class xyz
public String askQuestion()throws Exception
 {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is 2+2?");
            sResponse = response;
        }
    });
   return sResopnse;
}
```

Comment: Except that it will return an empty string (run won't be executed yet by the time you reach the return statement).

Comment: Yes, the method will return before the UI operation completes which means `sBuilder.toString()` will be called before the response is appended. That and this doesn't help me if I need to return `boolean` or `int`.

Comment: @assylias: yeah The method should have use `invokeAndWait` indeed

Comment: Okay, so now it will work for a `String`, but what about an `int` or `boolean` or even a `File`?

Comment: @LoganDam You could use a `final Object[] result = new Object[1];` and in `run`: `result[0] = whateverYouWant;`.

Comment: @LoganDam: In that case use a field in class say `iValue` for `int` or `bVal` for `boolean` and assign the inputvalue to them and then return the appropriate value via the variable.

Comment: So I either have to make an Object array and assign to that or make a class field like I said in my OP?

Comment: @LoganDam: Yes , but in case of Object array make sure that you  typecast the obtained value to appropriate type .